# Change "Add to Cart" to allow for size / variant selection on Shopify with Slide Cart app

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a collection page set up on Shopify which includes a link to 'add to cart' however this automatically adds an extra small size to the cart. In addition, I have an app called 'Slide Cart' which adds a cart drawer to the page.

I am trying to either amend the add to cart to allow for selecting a size OR amending the slide cart interface to allow customers to toggle between sizes. Currently if a product is added to cart from the collection page, it does not allow customers to change sizes limiting the usefulness of the cart drawer.

Site is using minimal theme with pagefly builder.

Site: Thebumovement.com
Pword: bum

Are there any coding work arounds for this?

Comment: Please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: thanks robert, i will update and re-post the problem